# Android Building fatal error: map: No such file

Tags: android, build, stl, customization

Following the instructions on https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html, up to building, and using `lunch full_grouper-user` to generate the makefiles.  The Android source builds just fine for about 5 minutes, then stops on this error:

```
target arm C++: libwebrtc_system_wrappers <= external/webrtc/src/system_wrappers/source/map.cc
In file included from external/webrtc/src/system_wrappers/source/map.cc:11:0:external/webrtc/src/system_wrappers/source/../interface/map_wrapper.h:14:15: fatal error: map: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebrtc_system_wrappers_intermediates/map.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Any advice?  Looks like the compiler can't find the STL headers, very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem.  Got Android compiling for Nexus 7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

The issue here related to having NDK_ROOT defined in the environment variables (in my .bashrc).  There is a bug in the webrtc makefiles that caused it to ignore including STL because NDK_ROOT was defined.

So just make sure NDK_ROOT is not defined at all when building.